# Filter $gte and $lte a string in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

how to add filter with $gte and $lte a string value? I have a StaredAt but is a string type. How to filter in a range, for example:

Range: 2022-02-02 / 2022-02-04

I tried this but throw and exception:

```
var subfilter = new BsonDocument("$expr",
                new BsonDocument("$gte",
                    new BsonArray {
                        new BsonDocument("$toDate", "$StartDate"),
                        From
                    }
                )
            );

        var subfilterTo = new BsonDocument("$expr",
                new BsonDocument("$lte",
                    new BsonArray {
                new BsonDocument("$toDate", "$StartDate"),
                To
                    }
                )
            );
```

The exception is:

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command find failed: An object representing an expression must have exactly one field: { $gte: [ { $toDate: "$StartDate" }, new Date(1663124400000) ], $lte: [ { $toDate: "$StartDate" }, new Date(1663210799000) ] }
```

Comment: Convert `startDate` to a date before comparing. (I am not  familiar with the c# driver, so can't give you syntax)

Comment: @ISAE how can i convert something that I don't have a value? Is a filter

Comment: I believe that there is something wrong when you merge both `subfilter` and `subfilterTo` into a single query. Can you provide the complete code for how you build the query? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the C# Mongodb Linq provider.

That way you can avoid the nesting of the BsonDocuments and it can be as simple as:

`collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.From > StartDate && x.To < EndDate)`

Answer (score 0):

In order to use $expr to convert the strings to dates, you can create a single expression with a AND condition that combines both conditions:

```
new BsonDocument("$expr", new BsonDocument("$and", new BsonArray
        {
            new BsonDocument("$gte", 
            new BsonArray
                {
                    new BsonDocument("$toDate", "$StartDate"),
                    From
                }),
            new BsonDocument("$lte", 
            new BsonArray
                {
                    new BsonDocument("$toDate", "$StartDate"),
                    To
                })
        }));
```

This is equivalent to the following query:

```
{
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      { $gte: [{ $toDate: "$StartDate" }, From] },
      { $lte: [{ $toDate: "$StartDate" }, To] },
    ];
  }
}
```

As a sidenote: if you convert the dates from string to date data types in the documents, this simplifies the query and will improve query performance because you can use an index.